# fullcalendar2 with minTime and maxTime for each weekdays

Tags: jquery, time, calendar, fullcalendar

Is it possible to have the different minTime and maxTime for each weekdays in fullcalenar (the hours at the left side)?

Example:

- Monday: 08:00 - 18:00
- Tuesday:  08:00 - 18:00
- Wednesday:  10:00 - 19:00
- Thursday:  13:00 - 20:00
- ...

Default in fullcalendar has minTime and maxTime but it's for all weekdays.

Thanks and Regards,
Tin

Comment: Hello, what ended you up doing?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same scenario to change the `minTime` and `maxTime`. Unfortunately there is no any option to change it dynamically rather than you reinitialise the calendar when you traverse `back` and `forth` in the calendar. Also you need to do some modifications in the `fullcalendar.js` in the `prev` and `next` function. Something like this is what you need to do in the `prev` function

```
var day = new Date(currentView.start.getTime() - 86400000).getDay();
```

and in the `next` function

```
var day = currentView.end.getDay();
```

and then you can find the time by using the day value. And then pass minTime and maxTime value in the calendar as parameters. Also before passing it `remove` the calendar and again call it through method call.